# Animate PNGs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, png, jquery-animate

Is there a simple plugin or some robust code that would allow me to animate PNGs with a simple start and stop method? TSM, Alex.

---

[Edit: I made a jQuery plugin that animates PNGs. Will post when it's all done.]

Comment: do you mean controlling APNGs? or animating multiple PNGs?

Comment: Do you just want to rotate through several PNG files to produce an animation, or fade/something more complex?

Comment: Rotate through several PNG files to produce an animation.

Comment: Did you ever post this? Would be interested in seeing it!

Comment: http://isthatclear.com/jquery/canimate/ did what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this is not an "off-the-shelf" plugin, you may be intrested in checking out the following tutorial:

- [Building an Animated Cartoon Robot with jQuery](http://css-tricks.com/jquery-robot/)

It uses PNG images for all the layers. It explains how to implement a `startHim()` method, which I'm sure you'll be able to convert into a `stopHim()`. You may probably be able to skim through it, unless you are trying to do something similar.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer in the mean time. I may take it upon myself to create such a plugin. I'll post more here if/when i do.